SOLANA - SWAP - Balance change is not displayed when using Jupiter swap API
I'm using jupiter quote/swap endpoints to get transaction string.
https://www.quicknode.com/docs/solana/swap
But when signing transaction, wallets don't display balance change at all, even though it gets correctly performed after confirming this transaction.
Simulating transaction on main net succeeds.
`
    const connection = new Connection('https://solana-rpc.publicnode.com')
    const serializedTx = result.transactionString // the swapTransaction string of /swap endpoint
    const binaryString = atob(serializedTx);
    const transactionBuffer = Uint8Array.from(binaryString, (char) => char.charCodeAt(0));
    const versionedTransaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(transactionBuffer);
    console.log(await connection.simulateTransaction(versionedTransaction)) // success

    const signedTransaction = await wallet.value.adapter.signTransaction(versionedTransaction);

    console.log("Signed Transaction:", signedTransaction);`

But when sign happens, i see window like this:
enter image description here
Expected result:
enter image description here
